# python lirc keyup function?

Tags: python, lirc

I a using [lirc for python](https://github.com/tompreston/python-lirc). This is working pretty good, but I miss one function: In my tests only a code was sent, when a button was pressed. Now, I want to print a code, while the key is pressed. In other words, a function should be started by "key down" and stopped by "key up". Using just the `lirc.nextcode()` is not working, because only the "key down" event is captured.

So, is there any trick to detect a "key up" with python?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, lircd has the --release option which generates synthetic release events, see the manpage at http://lirc.org/html/lircd.html

There is also the lircd-uinput add-on which feeds the kernel with the lirc keypress events. These events are made available on a /dev/input device, complete with repetition and release events. See the lircd-uinput manpage at http://lirc.org/html/lircd-uinput.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in lirc. Think about it like this: a infrared signal from a remote is either received or not, there is no such thing as a keyup event, not even a keydown event.

You will have to code your own key up and key down events.
Have a look at the way you can make configuration files, specifically the part about delay: http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html
Configure in such a way that many events are sent per second.

Then, put lirc in non-blocking mode (see https://github.com/tompreston/python-lirc). You can then loop over lirc.nextcode() and if it returns no  event or returns an event for a different key, you have your key up event.

Comment: By using `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` and pressing a button, I can see that signals are received continuously. I am not sure how the delay option of the lirc config can help me, because it just ignores some repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my answer here:
[LIRC - How to use as keyboard command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536799/lirc-how-to-use-as-keyboard-command/64515643#64515643)

Basically, you can edit the lircd-uinput.service to add the release event for you.  There may be a way to programmatically add the release event, but I don't know how to do that.  Having the service do it is very responsive, and works well for my application.

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/lircd-uinput.service

####find this line####
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lircd-uinput 

####change to#########
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lircd-uinput --add-release-events

#then reload/restart all the lircd services...
```